# Why is np.unique(array.tolist()) quicker than np.unique(array) when array is type string and the opposite is true for floats?

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the arrays below and the test results.
Why is running with `tolist()` quicker when array elements are strings and not quicker when array elements are floats?

```
bunch_of_strings = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice(list(ascii_letters), (10000, 4))).sum(1).values
bunch_of_floats = np.random.rand(10000)
```

[image]

Comment: wouldn't it have something to do with the "array will be flattened if not 1D" and the fact that elements in the array are strings, so also subscriptable? By converting to `list`, there's no ambiguity. Looks like a bug anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `bunch_of_strings` array has object dtype, meaning it gets none of the benefits of NumPy. It's basically just a worse list with a bunch of NumPy-specific overhead and a fixed size.

When you call `tolist`, `np.unique` has to convert the list back into an array. When it does, it makes an array of dtype `dtype('S4')`, a string dtype. The benefits of a non-object dtype save a lot of time in the `np.unique` call, more than is lost in the extra conversions.

In contrast, `bunch_of_floats` has float64 dtype, and the array->list->array conversion doesn't change that. It just wastes time.